# Rounding mode with BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

The following code which uses `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`,

```
BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("4.5");
value1=value1.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

BigDecimal value2 = new BigDecimal("6.5");
value2=value2.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

System.out.println(value1+"\n"+value2);
```

displays `4` and `6` respectively. It seems to me that it should display `5` and `7` respectively because the digit to the left of the discarded fractional part (which is 5 in this case) is **odd**. In this case, it performs `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`

And in case of `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`,  `RoundingMode.UP` is performed when the  discarded fractional part is >=0.5 (which is true), otherwise `RoundingMode.DOWN` is performed.

Comment: `4` and `6` are the `EVEN` in `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`.  `.5` is the `HALF` part.

Comment: For posterity, I had to read this a few times to get it as well.  An example that made sense to me is that if you're rounding 6.5 then you are an equal distance from 6 and 7.  Because 6 is even, you chose that one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The behavior is well described in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN):

> Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" **unless both
>   neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even
>   neighbor**.

So given the number 4.5, which falls right in the middle of the range of numbers between 4 and 5, when you call:

```
BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("4.5").setScale(RoundingMode.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

The runtime needs to figure out which neighbor to round too, aka, should it round to 4, or to 5? Normally it would round based on which value 4.5 is closer to, but in this case its close to ***both*** neighbors. Instead of arbitrarily picking the final result though, it picks the even number. This is the behavior of `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`. If you wanted to, you could specify `ROUND_HALF_UP` and the final result would have been 5, and not 4. Also, keep in mind that the determination about how to round is based on what the final result would be (and not on the decimal portion of the big decimal, as you seem to have assumed).

Comment: I didn't get this quoted text.

Comment: @Tiny, it means that if the number you are rounding, in half even mode, falls in the center of the range between an odd and even number, that the even number will be the result of the rounding operation.

Comment: If you can, please explain with a simple example. I find this very basic thing difficult to understand and personally, I cannot consult someone to help.

Comment: Added some detail to my answer, hope that helps

Comment: I'm using Java 8. There are no method `setScale(RoundingMode roundingMode)` in BigDecimal, the closest method is `setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode)` and there are no  variable `RoundingMode.ROUND_HALF_EVEN`. I suppose that variables changed.