# Java String.format() with HALF_EVEN rounding

Tags: java, string-formatting, formatter

I'd like to use **String.format()** to format some BigDecimals as part of a string:

```
// Example:
String getPrice( String pattern )
{
  BigDecimal price = basePrice.multiply( BigDecimal.ONE.add( vatRate ) );
  BigDecimal priceInPence = price.multiply( new BigDecimal( "100" ) );
  BigDecimal annualPrice = price.multiply( new BigDecimal( "365" ) );

  return String.format( pattern, priceInPence, annualPrice );
}

String myPrice1 = getPrice( "Your price is %1$.3fp/day (£2$.2f/year) including VAT" );
// --> "Your price is 32.100p/day (£117.16/year) including VAT"

String myPrice2 = getPrice( "Around £%2$.0f annualy" );
// --> "Around £117 annually"
```

However the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dnbdec) for String.format() say that any rounding of BigDecimals will be done with HALF_UP rounding, whereas I need HALF_EVEN.

I know how to manually set the scale of BigDecimals ([Set specific precision of a BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482889/set-specific-precision-of-a-bigdecimal)) - but in this case I want to be able to use an arbitrary pattern string (including non-numeric pattern elements), so I won't know in advance what scale to use.

My question is therefore:

- can I **set the rounding mode used by String.format()**? OR
- is there **another formatter or library** that would format the numbers as in my example?

Comment: Take a look at java.math.MathContext. You can construct a MathContext using a java.math.RoundingMode (HALF_EVEN), and then pass that to the constructor of BigDecimal or to one of the multiply methods: `multiply(BigDecimal multiplicand, MathContext mc)`

Comment: @mttdbrd - sorry, I should have made clear I need arbitrary precision, based on the pattern (see my edit above).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482889/set-specific-precision-of-a-bigdecimal and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352229/rounding-mode-with-bigdecimal-in-java

Comment: @ComputerFellow - sorry, those are answers about BigDecimals, my question is about changing the rounding mode used by String.Format()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really "solid" advice to add 5000 lines of dead-weight code to your project! From what I see, the Formatter will not set scale unless it is already set to what is needed. So help it out, parse the format string and set your scale:

```
public static String getPrice(String pattern) {
    BigDecimal basePrice = new BigDecimal("23");
    BigDecimal vatRate = new BigDecimal("0.5");
    BigDecimal price = basePrice.multiply(BigDecimal.ONE.add(vatRate));
    BigDecimal priceInPence = price.multiply(new BigDecimal("100"));
    BigDecimal annualPrice = price.multiply(new BigDecimal("365"));

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("%(\\d+)\\$.(\\d+)f").matcher(pattern);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String index = matcher.group(1);

        int scale = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));

        if (index.equals("1"))
            priceInPence = priceInPence.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        else if (index.equals("2"))
            annualPrice = annualPrice.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    }

    return String.format(pattern, priceInPence, annualPrice);
}
```

with these numbers I get this output:

> Your price is 3450.000p/day (£12592.50/year) including VAT
>
> Around £12592 annualy

So it applies correct rounding.

Comment: I like this approach. It could be even better if it was extended a bit to handle the case where a token is used more than once with different scales: getPrice( "Around £%2$.0f annualy (£%2.2f to be exact)" );

Answer (score 3):

*can I set the rounding mode used by String.format()?* 
Short answer: no.

*is there another formatter or library that would format the numbers as in my example?*
The BigDecimal is converted internally via  `new MathContext(compPrec)` or plain `HALF_UP`. 
You can take the code of `java.util.Formatter` of the latest (or your preferred) version Java and modify the creation of the MathContext to use HALF_EVEN. It should be 10-15minutes work. But then you need a custom method to mimic `String.format`:

```
public static String format(String format, Object... args) {
    return new FormatterHALF_EVEN().format(format, args).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the scale with the rounding mode you like, and include the values in the format string *as* strings, using `BigDecimal#toString()`.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know what scale to use until runtime: the precision information is in the pattern String.