# Java : confusing division result with 2 doubles

Tags: java, math

Can anyone explain what's going on here? My calculator insists that the result of equitation is 13201.

```
double test = 132.01/0.01D;
System.out.println(test); <- 13200.999999999998
```

Probably, this is very simple question, but I really don't understand. Most of questions in SO on similar topic involves Integer and Double.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5320080

Comment: Use strictfp please.

Comment: you can always use setRoundingMode with DecimalFormat if you want to format it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306355/java-convert-a-format-string

Comment: Double division is replaced during compile time itself. Also if you try to print  132.01 direclty then look into class file,the value is actually 132.00999999999999D which should explain why you got your answer... You can use Jade decompiler for the same

Comment: There's nothing wrong; this is how IEEE floating point numbers work.